# Tips or assistance in drawing maps?

Tags: dnd-5e, art

I'm going to be running a 5.0 dnd campaign in a few months, and i'd like to draw out the terrain on main cities beforehand, but my artist skills are lacking. I have flying chunks of land, oceans, and other various landscapes in mind.

Tips, suggestions, or maybe anyone willing to assist?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPG.Stackexchange.com! Unfortunately this post is too broad for our format here. We'd love to help you with your 5e campaign, but questions have to be sufficiently narrow as to only have a couple of possible answers.

Comment: There are technique tutorials around for map making (specific to fantasy gaming, even).  Some googling will probably find you some.

Comment: I agree that the post is too broad, but disagree slightly with how @waxeagle put it: it's not (in my mind) that a post need be narrow enough to only have a couple of answers, it's that a post need to be constructed tightly enough that a passing voter could sensibly weigh in on how well any given answer addresses the question.